# TypeScript - ReactRouter | Arrow function captures the global value of 'this' which implicitly has type 'any'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm rendering a component via React Router 4 using `render={() => </Component />}`

I need to pass state to the given component i.e: `<Game />`

```
export const Routes: React.SFC<{}> = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
    <Route path="/play-game" render={() => <Game {...this.state} />} />
    <Redirect to="/" />
  </Switch>
)
```

To which TS breaks saying:

`The containing arrow function captures the global value of 'this' which implicitly has type 'any'`
[image]

The final goal is to be able to pass the `Routes` to my main app: i.e:

```
export default class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
  public state = {
    // state logic
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Navigation />
            <Routes />
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )
  }
}
```

How could I apply the correct types to suppress this TypeScript error?

Comment: If you are using the arrow function in an `export const` who do you expect `this` to be ?

Comment: Have you looked into the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) function previously?

Comment: I take `this` would belong to const Routes, which is why is the error? How could I remedy that? I'm still pretty raw.

Comment: I suggest getting familiar with `this` in JS - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arrow functions do not have lexical contexts, so any invocation of `this` inside the body of an arrow will degenerate to its value in the outer scope. This is what TS is complaining about.

For your problem of passing the state around you need to pass this as a prop to the `Routes` component which will dispatch it to the relevant route.

```
export default class App extends Component<{}, AppState> {
  public state = {
    // state logic
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <Navigation />
            <Routes state={this.state}/>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )
  }
}

// you need to pass the correct type to React.SFC<>
// probably something along React.SFC<{ state: State }>
// where State is the type of `state` field in App.
export const Routes: React.SFC<...> = ({ state }) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Home} />
    <Route path="/play-game" render={() => <Game {...state} />} />
    <Redirect to="/" />
  </Switch>
)
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, I just lost you on `where State is the type of state field in App.`  Right now I'm getting a `cannot find name State'

Comment: What I meant is that the signature of the Routes component is likely incorrect
and should probably be `React.SFC<{ state: AppState }>` as it receives a prop named
`state` which is of same type as the `state` field in the `App` component. Your
Game component should also reflect this. While researching this I also stumbled
upon a deprecation notice for this signature, following the announcement of the
`hooks` api probably https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L446.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I'll keep reading on the topic as well.